# how to close a window in pyqt5 and terminate the program? program gets stuck

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to create a window in pyqt5 and then close it. For some reason the program does not exit after closing the window. It gets stuck. I have been reading several related posts but none give a clear answer.

I have already tried code such as "self.object.close()", "app.quit()", even "self.object.destroy()", but all work in the same way. The only thing that really closes the window is by clicking the x (close) at the window itself. But this is not the behavior I need. I would like to close the window using my code.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui 
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal

class window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()        
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 480, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Hello World')        
        self.setWindowLayout()

    def setWindowLayout(self):
        self.w = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)         
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Hello World Label') 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)                 
        self.w.setLayout(self.layout) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    main_window = window()
    main_window.show()    
    main_window.close() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Once I close the window using 
`main_window.close()`. I want my program to exit.

I apologize if this was resolved in a different post. I searched the answer and none solves my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that it is a bug since according to the docs the application should be closed if there is no top-level window but it seems that it is not verified if the closing of the window is not after the event-loop starts. A workaround is to use `QTimer.singleShot(0, ...)` to close the window:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()        
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 480, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Hello World')        
        self.setWindowLayout()

    def setWindowLayout(self):
        self.w = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)         
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Hello World Label') 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)                 
        self.w.setLayout(self.layout) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    main_window = window()
    main_window.show()    
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, main_window.close) # <---
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: your workaround works! I will see if I can report the bug. Gracias for the quick reply.